# Git clone lfs Smudge error/404 error when cloning after merging from fork

Tags: git, gitlab, git-lfs

I have a project, lets call it masterProjects/lfsTestRepo. I clone masterProjects/lfsTestRepo, run `git lfs install` and `git lfs track *.rpm` then I add the .gitattributes file, commit and push my changes.

Then I fork the repo into myProjects/lfsTestRepo. Then I clone myProjects/lfsTestRepo, add a bunch files, including some rpms, add, commit, and push my changes.

Then I go into gitlab, create a merge request from myProjects/lfsTestRepo to masterProjects/lfsTestRepo. Everything looks good in gitlab so we accept the merge request.

Now when I try to pull or re-clone masterProjects/lfsTestRepo I get a Smudge error on the first rpm file it tries to download. If I run it with `git lfs install --skip-smudge` then I get a [404] Object does not exist on the server or you don't ahve permissions to access it. However if I go into gitlab and navigate to the rpm files in masterProjects/lfsTestRepo I can download the rpms files just fine through the web interface.

If I fork myProjects/lfsTestRepo again, that one can be cloned just fine.

Is there something else I have to configure locally? Is there something I have to configure in gitlab? Does gitlab just not work when pushing lfs files from repos up?

Comment: What does `git lfs fsck` say?

Comment: ```git lfs fsck``` says ```objects: openError: blah.rpm could not be checked: no such file or directory``` and ```objects: repair: moving corrupt objects to .git/lfs/bad```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never really figured out this issue, but to resolve it we set up a new server, installed Gitlab, imported our backup and everything worked fine.

My only guess is that it had something to do with the fact that the original server had been running so long I don't think gitlab even supported LFS when we first started using it. So there must of have been something that never actually upgraded correctly but didn't throw any errors and wasn't an issue until we finally started trying to use LFS.

Answer (score 1):

What it sounds like is happening is that `masterProject` doesn't have the LFS objects it should have, especially since a new clone of just the `masterProject` repo can't download all of them.

This sounds like a bug in Gitlab. Gitlab should handle the LFS objects added via a merge.

Can you try this:

1. Clone `myProjects/lfsTestRepo` to a new directory.
2. Ensure LFS has properly downloaded the files:

```
git lfs fsck
```

3. Add `masterProject/lfsTestRepo` as a new remote:

```bash
git remote add mproj git@gitlab.mycompany.com:masterProject/lfsTestRepo
```

4. Push your branch from `myProjects/lfsTestRepo` into the `masterProject/lfsTestRepo` repo:

```bash
git push mproj master:temp/lfs-fix-push
```

(Replace `master` with whatever your branch with the changes is called.)

That `push` *should* upload any missing LFS objects into the `masterProject/lfsTestRepo` repo.

You can test whether the needed LFS objects are present in `masterProject/lfsTestRepo` by cloning that project to a new directory.

Comment: This did work, however normal developers won't be able to push to masterProject projects at all and are required to use merge requests. Is there something I can do with my gitlab configuration to get merge requests to handle lfs objects correctly?

Comment: Pretty sure this is just a bug in Gitlab -- it should just handle it without anything more complex than enabling LFS. You're not out of space on the volume, for one. Without diving deeper, it may not be able to be fixed. One thing I would do to make sure it's not something messed up with your settings, is to launch a new instance and try to repro there. You could also try making sure you're running the latest version of Gitlab. Check the server logs too if they indicate a failure during the merge.

Comment: What log should I try looking at?

Comment: @JJJ Not sure, I don't have experience hosting and debugging Gitlab, but I would start with `/home/git/gitlab/log/application.log`. See [the official Log System page](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/logs/) for info on how to use Gitlab logging.